# The JSON that defines my nav has header types and category types that I'd like to convert to nested UL LI elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

My JSON is like so:

```
{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "5",
     "catName": "header"
},
{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
     "catName": "category"
},
{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
     "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "5",
    "catName": "header"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
}
```

And I would like to build a nested UL LI system to render HTML that looks like this:

- header

  - category
  - category
  - category
- header

  - category
  - category

I've tried various nested loops but I can't seem to sort it out.

```
<!-- category nav -->
    <div id="sideNav">
        <ul class="sideUl">
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- end category nav -->

$.each(object(i, value){
        if( value.categoryDisplaySubTypeId == "5" ) {
            $('.sideUl').append("<li>"+object.catName+"</li>);

        }
        if( value.categoryDisplaySubTypeId == "10" ) {
            $('.sideUl').append("<ul>");    
            $('.sideUl').append("<li>"+object.catName+"</li>);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the JSON should be an array as follow:

```
var obj = [{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "5",
     "catName": "header"
},
{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
     "catName": "category"
},
{
     "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
     "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "5",
    "catName": "header"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
},
{
    "categoryDisplaySubTypeId": "10",
    "catName": "category"
}];
```

Then iterate over the array using a for each loop as given below:

```
obj.forEach( function (arrayItem)
{
    if( arrayItem.categoryDisplaySubTypeId == "5" ) {

            $('.sideUl').append("<li>"+arrayItem.catName+"</li>");

        }
      if( arrayItem.categoryDisplaySubTypeId == "10" ) {
            $('.sideUl').append("<ul><li>"+arrayItem.catName+"</li></ul>");    

        }
});
```

Problems in your code were:

1. No proper closing double quotes.
2. No closing `<ul>` tags.
3. `<ul>` and `<li>` were appended inccorectly.

See the working fiddle here: "https://jsfiddle.net/6zsf2hbs/3/"

Comment: thank you so much!!! that sorted it out. I didn't really think about making the sub list with multiple ULs, but it works...